# Прототип: int f( char *a, char * b ); Отсортировать символы в алфавитном порядке. Поиск минимального в исходной строке, запись в выходную строку

Tags: c, строки, функции, сортировка

Написать на языке "С" или "С++" функцию, удовлетворяющую следующим требованиям, вызвать ее в программе main( )

Прототип: int f( char *a, char * b );
Параметры: a - указатель исходной стpоки; b - указатель результирующей стpоки
Назначение: отсортировать символы в строке в алфавитном порядке. Алгоритм: поиск минимального в исходной строке, запись в выходную строку.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка и как необходимо сделать? У меня постоянно выводит **a'(рандомный символ)**
Код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int f( char *a, char * b );

int main()
{
    char *input;
    char *output;
    
    input = (char*)malloc(256*sizeof(char));
    output = (char*)malloc(256*sizeof(char));
    
    scanf("%s", input);
    
    f(input,output);
    
    printf("%s", output);
    
return 0;}


int f( char *a, char *b )
{
    char i, j;
    char temp;
    for (i = 0; i != '\0'; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j != '\0'; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] < a[j]) b[i] = a[i];
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неверно реализован алгоритм сортировки. Попробуйте так:

```
int f( char *a, char *b )
{
    char i;
    int len, out_pos, min_pos, min_sym;    
    
    // Цикл повторяется, пока исходная строка не сократится до 1 символа
    out_pos = 0;
    while ( (len = strlen(a)) > 1 ) {
        // Ищем минимальный символ
        min_sym = 256; // Самый большой код символа
        min_pos = -1; // Позиция мин. символа пока не известна
        for (i = 0; i<len; i++) {
            if (a[i]<min_sym) {
               min_sym = a[i];
               min_pos = i;
            }
        }

        // Переносим его в выходной буфер
        b[out_pos] = min_sym;
        b[out_pos+1] = '\0';
        out_pos++;
       
        // Укорачиваем исходную строку
        for (i=min_pos; i<len; i++) a[i] = a[i+1];
        a[len] = '\0';
    }
    
   // Переносим последний символ
        b[out_pos] = a[0];
        b[out_pos+1] = '\0';
    
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо!